How to swipe forwards or backwards through an array using the fling gesture
I have a list of items that I want the user to be able to swipe through using the fling gesture. When the user swipes up or right they will move forward to the next item (1, 2, 3, etc). When the user swipes down or left they will iterate backwards through the list (3, 2, 1 etc). Currently I'm getting an error [Reanimated] Tried to synchronously call a non-worklet function 'bound dispatchSetState' on the UI thread. I've tried using React-Native-Pager-View with a fling gesture also but could not make this work either.
const Home = props => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const getAffirmations = useSelector(state => state.affirmationsSlice);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getTitles = getAffirmations.affirmations.map(m => {
    return m.title;
  });

  const flingGestureUp = Gesture.Fling()
    .direction(Directions.UP)
    .onEnd(() =>
      setCurrentIndex(prev => (prev + 1) % getAffirmations.affirmations.length),
    );

  const flingGestureDown = Gesture.Fling()
    .direction(Directions.DOWN)
    .onEnd(() => console.log('SwipedDown'));

  const upOrDown = Gesture.Exclusive(flingGestureUp, flingGestureDown);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <GestureDetector gesture={upOrDown}>
        {/* <PagerView
          initialPage={0}
          orientation={'vertical'}
          onPageScroll={() => handleSwipe()}> */}
        <View style={lightGlobalStyles.affirmationContainer}>
          <Text
            style={[
              lightGlobalStyles.affirmationText,
              theme.theme === true
                ? themes.whiteText
                : theme.theme2 === true
                ? themes.yellowText
                : theme.theme5 === true
                ? themes.darkText
                : themes.offWhiteText,
            ]}>
            {getTitles[currentIndex]}
          </Text>
          <View style={style.makeFavoritePosition}>
            <MakeFavoriteIcon currentIndex={currentIndex} />
          </View>
          <Background />
        </View>
        {/* </PagerView> */}
      </GestureDetector>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;


After more research here is a solution to my problem.
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  Directions,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {useSharedValue, withTiming} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const Home = props => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const getAffirmations = useSelector(state => state.affirmationsSlice);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getTitles = getAffirmations.affirmations.map(m => {
    return m.title;
  });

  const position = useSharedValue(0);

  const handleUpAndLeft = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(prev => (prev + 1) % getAffirmations.affirmations.length);
  };

  const handleRightAndDown = () => {
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
      setCurrentIndex(getAffirmations.affirmations.length - 1);
    } else {
      setCurrentIndex(prev => (prev - 1) % getAffirmations.affirmations.length);
    }
  };

  const flingGestureRight = Gesture.Fling()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .direction(Directions.RIGHT)
    .onStart(e => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value + 10, {duration: 100});
      handleRightAndDown();
    });
  const flingGestureUp = Gesture.Fling()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .direction(Directions.UP)
    .onStart(e => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value + 10, {duration: 100});
      handleUpAndLeft();
    });
  const flingGestureLeft = Gesture.Fling()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .direction(Directions.LEFT)
    .onStart(e => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value - 10, {duration: 100});
      handleUpAndLeft();
    });
  const flingGestureDown = Gesture.Fling()
    .runOnJS(true)
    .direction(Directions.DOWN)
    .onStart(e => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value - 10, {duration: 100});
      handleRightAndDown();
    });

  const gestureDirections = Gesture.Exclusive(
    flingGestureLeft,
    flingGestureRight,
    flingGestureUp,
    flingGestureDown,
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <GestureDetector gesture={gestureDirections}>
        <Animated.View style={lightGlobalStyles.affirmationContainer}>
          <Text
            style={[
              lightGlobalStyles.affirmationText,
              theme.theme === true
                ? themes.whiteText
                : theme.theme2 === true
                ? themes.yellowText
                : theme.theme5 === true
                ? themes.darkText
                : themes.offWhiteText,
            ]}>
            {getTitles[currentIndex]}
          </Text>
          <View style={style.makeFavoritePosition}>
            <MakeFavoriteIcon currentIndex={currentIndex} />
          </View>
          <Background />
          </Animated.View>
          </GestureDetector>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };

    export default Home;

